# ReactionCollector filter doesn't work with one of the emojis

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
if (cmd === "test") {
  message.channel.send("Pick a reaction").then(async function(message) {
    await message.react("");
    await message.react("");
    await message.react("");
    const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === "" || reaction.emoji.name === "" || reaction.emoji.name === "" && reaction.message.author.id === "266315409735548928";
    let collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, {
      time: 15000
    });
    collector.on('collect', (reaction, collector) => {
      switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
        case "":
          message.channel.send("Picked N");
          break;
        case "":
          message.channel.send("Picked B");
          break;
        case "":
          message.channel.send("Picked O");
          break;
      }
    });
    collector.on('end', collected => {
      return;
    });
  });
}
```

For some reason my code stopped working today: when I switch the  and  in the filter it does work but when I leave it as it is now, nothing happens when  is picked.
What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the  itself, but the way logical operators work. Let's say you have this expression:

```
first || second && third
```

That means that the program is first going to check `first`, then if that's `true` since there's a `||` after it, it will stop, otherwise, it will check for `second`. When it checks for `second` it doesn't stop if its `true`, because you put a `&&` after it. That expression translates to this one:

```
first || (second && third)
```

Your code works with the first two reactions because it's not checking the id, while it does it in the third (and it happens not to be the same: `false`)

I suggest you to switch to this expression:

```
["", "", ""].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && reaction.message.author.id == '266315409735548928';
```

This does the same thing but in a more compact way. If you still want to use the old way, write this:

```
 (reaction.emoji.name === "" || reaction.emoji.name === "" || reaction.emoji.name === "") && reaction.message.author.id === "266315409735548928";
```

Sidenote: since you wrote that it didn't work with the , it won't work with this code too because `reaction.message.author.id == '266315409735548928'` still returns `false`. 
If you were trying to check if the reaction was added by you, you should use `user.id == 'your id'`.
I don't see the point in checking the ID of the message's author since the message was sent by the bot and the `ReactionCollector` works only with that message.